# Can the F-35 (and F-22) do the Kvochur Bell maneuver?

Tags: airplane, f-35, f-22, maneuverability

Can the F-35 (and F-22) do the Kvochur Bell maneuver? Surprisingly I didn’t find much about this on google. (Might’ve searched for the wrong thing though)

Comment: F-22 has thrust vectoring, so it most likely is able to do whatever. F-35 does not, so its ability to do fancy circus tricks is somewhat limited.

Comment: There's YouTube video of a Su-27 performing the maneuver. The nozzles aren't moving much if at all. It doesn't look like TVC is required. I haven't found a good description of the maneuver, but it looks like most maneuvering happens pre-stall, the back half of the maneuver is just a tail slide.

Comment: Come to think of it, the Su-27 doesn't even have TVC.

Comment: @JörgWMittag yeah those are some good points. I would love to see an F-35 do that maneuver! I think a lot of people would be surprised if it could.

Answer (score -3):

F22 can....Kvochur maneeuver otherwise known as a tailslide

Comment: The embedded video doesn't appear to be viewable without switching to YouTube?